# Reciting/singing Aḥeinu outside of the formal prayer setting and origin of tune

Tags: tefilla, torah-reading, song-poetry

Where, when and why did the prayer Aheinu begin to be recited outside of the liturgical context? It seems that it originated as and was restricted to being recited after reading from the Torah, however today it is often recited in other communal settings and contexts.

What is the source for the fairly ubiquitous *tune*?

Some examples:

[Motty Steinmetz (Hasidic)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdWzL0I1ZSU)

[Shai Abramson (IDF Rabbinate Band)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87Ooph8w1pk)

[Zaka volunteers](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/1s3omX6WGv0)

Text:

> אחינו כל בית ישראל, הנתונים בצרה ובשביה, העומדים בין בים ובין ביבשה
> ,המקום ירחם עליהם ויוציאם מצרה לרווחה, ומאפלה לאורה, ומשעבוד לגאולה,
> השתא בעגלה ובזמן קריב. ונאמר אמן

Translation:

> As for our brothers,​ the whole house of Israel, who are given over to
> trouble or captivity​, whether they abide on the sea or on the dry
> land: May God have mercy upon them, and bring them forth from trouble
> to enlargement, from darkness to light, and from subjugation to
> redemption, now speedily and at a near time. Let us say Amen.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, the examples you give are song renditions which isn’t all that uncommon for any number of tefillos

Comment: @ezra the examples are of the specific tune I am asking about. The presentation of multiple examples is in service of the claim that the tune is widely used.

Comment: It's a nice song. What is the question?

Comment: @NT I'm not sure what you are not understanding. This song is a prayer that historically had a specific liturgical context. It is now oft recited/sung in other contexts (this past Simhath Torah I synagogue I attended recited it during haqafoth, in years past I've heard it recited on 9 Abh, I recently observed it being recited during prayer gatherings for the situation in E"Y in both right wing and centrist settings, etc. ) The question is a) when/where/how did it begin to be recited outside of its historic setting and b) who composed the widely used tune. Is there anything else I can clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The song was popularised following its release by Abie Rotenberg.

It was composed in 1990 (see [here](https://mostlymusic.com/blogs/news-updates/15600789-an-interview-with-acheinu-composer-abie-rotenberg-as-we-continue-to-daven-to-bringbackourboys)) and first released on his [Lev V'nefesh 1](https://mostlymusic.com/products/lev-vanefesh-i-cd) CD.

In an interview (linked above) Abie provides more context:

> GC: When you composed Acheinu what was going in the world that had you adapt those words to the tune?
>
> AR: I don’t recall any particular reason for composing a tune to the words Acheinu. As we say in Yiddish, es felt nisht kein tzaros, there are always more than enough problems. But I do remember that in this instance, the melody was written specifically for those words, not just as a tune for which the words were chosen later.

As @JoelK observes from the interview, it became popular shortly after its release which coincided with the onset of the Gulf War.

Comment: He may not have composed it with a specific situation in mind, but as he notes in that interview, it became popular as it was released around the time of the Gulf War

Comment: True @JoelK thanks

Comment: war and the war machine

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! So is it your contention that before it was popularized via Abie Rotenberg's tune that it was generally otherwise restricted to its place in prayer until 1990?

Comment: @Deuteronomy as with any other song - either you know it or you don't. When a song becomes more well known it is sung more frequently...

Comment: @Dov that is true in a general sense, though it doesn't answer specifically whether this specific prayer was  sometimes recited/sung by people (irrespective of tune) outside of the original liturgical context, prior to 1990. I suspect not (or at least negligibly so) but don't objectively know that. It's okay if you do not know either, you've already got my +1 and answer acceptance :)

Comment: If the famous tune was not in existence prior to 1990, plausibly it wasn't as well known